# Adding cards on top of each other in Android using XML

Tags: xml, android-layout, kotlin, android-cardview

I am trying to make an app which consists of three cards and the cards will be stacked on top of each other and come up when I open it as shown in Designs below.

[image]

now when I click on team it should come up.

I tried to add an `OnClickListener` on it but it also detects the touch from behind another card.
Thanks for any answers in Advance

Comment: Make three similar cards which start from bottom of parent. Then by setting their heights or paddings, you will get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

you can make a animation 
add a onClick methot to textView mark and Team

when they click mark the animation can be work

Comment: you can make a animation then add a onClick methot to textView (mark and Team)

Comment: Thank you for your answer samil, but when I click on team and I have a setonclickListener on mark it detects the touch from under team, so even when I touch on team it detects touch on mark as well.
Thank you

Comment: so you can change them write codes under mark for team